# How can I start with deno.land?

Tags: deno

I working with NodeJS, but I know Deno is a future. I really want to learn Deno and contribute for it, but I don't know how can I start or really right roadmap I can build to follow in the right road.

I really wanna learn and control it. If community who has experience with self-taught with Deno, please help me to deep dive in Deno.

I completed a course about the basic Rust :D, and try to code some of demo with Deno!

Answer (score 4):

I started with Deno by writing a basic CLI application that fetched a value from a Postgres database and displayed it in the screen.

Currently I am writing an app on Deno/React for my company, but that has only made me realize that I don't really need to know much about Deno, but rather about the latest versions of JavaScript, since Deno doesn't deviate from normal JavaScript in any sense.

Read the API docs if you want to know what Deno offers([Deno docs](https://doc.deno.land/)), and learn TypeScript to get the most out of it.

Deno makes a strong emphasis in asynchronous programming as well, so you better start learning about async programmation in ES2020.

Finally, join the Discord channel for Deno. There are lots of people there that might help you with any Deno related question you may have.

Answer (score 2):

The Deno code is in GitHub, if you want to contribute, you can start doing a Draft PR to fix an existing issue, and I'm sure that some reviewers are going to help you to finish the PR in case of doubts.

https://github.com/denoland/deno

Also, there is a doc section about contributing:

https://github.com/denoland/deno/tree/master/docs/contributing